# Load a pretrained caffe model to lasagne?

Tags: python, machine-learning, caffe, lasagne

I am trying to reproduce the [Long-term Recurrent Convolutional Networks](http://arxiv.org/abs/1411.4389) paper.

I have a pretrained caffe model that I'd like to use in `theano`.
I have the [`.caffemodel`](http://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/~lisa_anne/single_frame_all_layers_hyb_flow_iter_50000.caffemodel) for this file, and the [`prototxt`](https://github.com/LisaAnne/lisa-caffe-public/blob/lstm_video_deploy/examples/LRCN_activity_recognition/train_test_singleFrame_flow.prototxt).
I have used the [lasagne example](https://github.com/Lasagne/Recipes/blob/master/examples/Using%20a%20Caffe%20Pretrained%20Network%20-%20CIFAR10.ipynb) to load the caffe weights to the caffe model.
This is the [code I used](http://pastebin.com/xdD3wZCe), but the data is not loaded to the lasagne model.
I check it by using the  `lasagne.layers.get_all_param_values(net)` command, which throws this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/anilil/projects/pycharm-community-5.0.4/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 2411, in <module>
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
  File "/home/anilil/projects/pycharm-community-5.0.4/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1802, in run
    launch(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "/media/anilil/Data/charm/mv_clean/Vgg_las.py", line 218, in <module>
    x=lasagne.layers.get_all_param_values(net)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/lasagne/layers/helper.py", line 439, in get_all_param_values
    params = get_all_params(layer, **tags)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/lasagne/layers/helper.py", line 353, in get_all_params
    return utils.unique(params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/lasagne/utils.py", line 157, in unique
    for el in l:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/lasagne/layers/helper.py", line 352, in <genexpr>
    params = chain.from_iterable(l.get_params(**tags) for l in layers)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get_params'
```

TRIAL/Test Code:-

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os
import sys
import lasagne
from lasagne.layers import InputLayer
from lasagne.layers import DenseLayer
from lasagne.layers import NonlinearityLayer
from lasagne.nonlinearities import rectify
from lasagne.layers import DropoutLayer
from lasagne.layers import Pool2DLayer as PoolLayer
from lasagne.layers.dnn import Conv2DDNNLayer as ConvLayer
from lasagne.nonlinearities import softmax
import theano as T
from lasagne.layers import LocalResponseNormalization2DLayer as LRN
sys.path.append('/home/anilil/projects/lstm/lisa-caffe-public/python/')
import caffe
from lasagne.utils import floatX
import numpy as np

def build_model():
    net = {}
    # Input layer
    net['input'] = InputLayer((None, 3, 227, 227))
    # First Conv Layer
    net['conv1'] = ConvLayer(net['input'], num_filters=96,filter_size=7, pad=0, flip_filters=False,stride=2,nonlinearity=rectify)
    net['pool1'] = PoolLayer(net['conv1'], pool_size=3,stride=2,mode='max')
    net['norm1'] = LRN(net['pool1'],alpha=0.0001,beta=0.75,n=5)
    # 2nd Conv Layer
    net['conv2'] = ConvLayer(net['norm1'], num_filters=384,filter_size=5, pad=0, flip_filters=False,stride=2,nonlinearity=rectify)
    net['pool2'] = PoolLayer(net['conv2'], pool_size=3,stride=2,mode='max')
    net['norm2'] = LRN(net['pool2'],alpha=0.0001,beta=0.75,n=5)
    # 3rd Conv Layer
    net['conv3'] = ConvLayer(net['norm2'], num_filters=512,filter_size=3, pad=1, flip_filters=False,nonlinearity=rectify)
    net['conv4'] = ConvLayer(net['conv3'], num_filters=512,filter_size=3, pad=1, flip_filters=False,nonlinearity=rectify)
    net['conv5'] = ConvLayer(net['conv4'], num_filters=384,filter_size=3, pad=1, flip_filters=False,nonlinearity=rectify)
    net['pool5'] = PoolLayer(net['conv5'], pool_size=3,stride=2,mode='max')
    net['fc6'] = DenseLayer(net['pool5'], num_units=4096,nonlinearity=rectify)
    net['fc6_dropout'] = DropoutLayer(net['fc6'], p=0.5)
    net['fc7'] = DenseLayer(net['fc6_dropout'], num_units=4096)
    net['fc7_dropout'] = DropoutLayer(net['fc7'], p=0.5)
    net['fc8-ucf'] = DenseLayer(net['fc7_dropout'], num_units=101, nonlinearity=None)
    net['prob'] = NonlinearityLayer(net['fc8-ucf'], softmax)

    return net

if __name__=="__main__":
    net = build_model()
    #net= load_caffe_weights(net,'/home/anilil/projects/lstm/lisa-caffe-public/examples/LRCN_activity_recognition/deploy_singleFrame.prototxt','/home/anilil/projects/lstm/lisa-caffe-public/examples/LRCN_activity_recognition/singleframe_flow/snaps/snapshots_singleFrame_flow_v2_iter_50000.caffemodel')
    caffe.set_device(0)
    caffe.set_mode_gpu()
    net_caffe = caffe.Net('/home/anilil/projects/lstm/lisa-caffe-public/examples/LRCN_activity_recognition/deploy_singleFrame.prototxt', '/home/anilil/projects/lstm/lisa-caffe-public/examples/LRCN_activity_recognition/singleframe_flow/snaps/snapshots_singleFrame_flow_v2_iter_50000.caffemodel', caffe.TEST)
    layers_caffe = dict(zip(list(net_caffe._layer_names), net_caffe.layers))

    for name, layer in net.items():
        try:
            layer.W.set_value(layers_caffe[name].blobs[0].data,borrow=True)
            layer.b.set_value(layers_caffe[name].blobs[1].data,borrow=True)
        except AttributeError:
            continue

    print ("Loaded the files without issues !!!!!!!!!!")
    x=lasagne.layers.get_all_param_values(net)
    print ("Saved Weights to the file without issues !!!!!!!!!!")
```

Comment: You should include your code in the question itself. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

try:

> x=lasagne.layers.get_all_param_values(net['prob'])

or make your net in this way:

```
def build_model():
    net = {}
    # Input layer
    net = InputLayer((None, 3, 227, 227))
    # First Conv Layer
    net = ConvLayer(net, num_filters=96,filter_size=7, pad=0,     flip_filters=False,stride=2,nonlinearity=rectify)
    net = PoolLayer(net, pool_size=3,stride=2,mode='max')
    ....
    net= NonlinearityLayer(net, softmax)
    return net
```